# Expresión regular que niegue

Tags: regex, grep

Necesito una expresion regular que busque archivos que no contengar por ejemplo

```
Twitter
```

he intentado `(^[twiter])` y otras más pero no me funcionan. 
Es para hacerlo por medio de *grep*

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Es decir, buscar archivos que no contengan la palabra "Twitter" en ninguna de las líneas? Iría bien una explicación más detallada, con algún ejemplo de ficheros que sí quieres, así como cuáles no, más que nada para descartar que busques que la coincidencia sea en el nombre del fichero y no en el contenido.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus recomendaciones y respuestas.
Siento si mi pregunta fue ambigua

Answer (score 1):

Negar una cadena con una expresión regular es complejo, pero por suerte grep lo simplifica mucho con la opción:

> ```
> -v, --invert-match
>               Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
> ```

Invierte el sentido de las coincidencias a buscar, por lo que puedes usar algo como

```
grep -v "[Tt]witter"
```

Answer (score 0):

Editando mi respuesta, porque contesté una sarta de imprecisiones (por no decirlo de otra manera), y revisando [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) respuesta. Sugiero que utilices algo como.

```
grep -P '^((?!Twitter).)*$' <<< 'Facebook
facebook
twitter
Twitter
instagram'
```

Donde el parámetro `-P` permite el uso de expresiones regulares de Perl. Al no usar este parámetro, o `-E` para las expresiones extendidas, `grep`, por defecto, utiliza expresiones regulares básicas.

A la vez que `grep` tiene una opción para negar un patrón a través del parámetro `-v`

> -v, --invert-match
>
> ```
> Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
> ```

Es decir

```
grep -v "Twitter" <<< 'facebook
instagram
Twitter
sonico
snapshit'
```

Comment: Explicación detallada, como siempre. De todos modos incidiría en que decir `[^Twitter]` va carácter a carácter, por lo que por ejemplo poner dos "t" es innecesario.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. Además, aquí hay un tema super interesante. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta!
Me ayudo mucho. :)

Comment: Harías un buen acto puntuándola positiva si consideras que es útil.